# Show that the equation is shift invariant and linear

Tags: signal-processing

I came across a question while studying signals and systems, and I am not able to prove it.
The question wants me to show that the following equation is shift invariant and linear. Showing that it is linear is not too difficult, but I am having a hard time showing that it is shift invariant.

$y(n)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{n} x(m)$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input $x(n)$ is shifted by $k$ units, we have
$$
y(n,k)=\sum^n_{m=-\infty}x(m-k)
$$
From the definition of shift invariant systems, we must have
$$
y(n-k)=\sum^{n-k}_{m=-\infty}x(m)=\sum^{n}_{v=-\infty}x(v-k)
$$

The right hand sides are equal therefore the system is shift invariant.